# How To Add Line Separators in AWS Kinesis in CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis-firehose

We are processing data (records) through Kinesis Stream going to Kinesis Firehose and then outputting the data to a file in our S3 bucket.

Currently, however, all the records are on the same line in our output file, but we want each record to be separated so they are on their own line.

Instead of something like:

```
Store1, 100, Broccoli
Store1, 101, Avocado
Store1, 102, Apple
```

It currently looks like:

```
Store1, 100, BroccoliStore1, 101, AvocadoStore1, 102, Apple
```

Here is our CloudFormation template:

```
Resources:
  MyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

  MyStream:
    Type: AWS::Kinesis::Stream
    Properties:
      Name: my-stream
      RetentionPeriodHours: 24
      ShardCount: 5

  MyFirehose:
    Type: AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream
    Properties:
      DeliveryStreamName: my-firehose
      DeliveryStreamType: KinesisStreamAsSource
      KinesisStreamSourceConfiguration:
        KinesisStreamARN:
          Fn::Sub: "${MyStream.Arn}"
        RoleARN:
          Fn::Sub: "${MyRole.Arn}"
      S3DestinationConfiguration:
        BufferingHints:
          IntervalInSeconds: 60
          SizeInMBs: 50
        CompressionFormat: UNCOMPRESSED
        Prefix: concessions/
        BucketARN:
          Fn::Sub: "${MyBucket.Arn}"
        RoleARN:
          Fn::Sub: "${MyRole.Arn}"
```

How can we add line separators so that the records show up on their own lines?

Comment: "You may want to add a record separator at the end of each record before you send it to Kinesis Firehose so that you can divide a delivered S3 object to individual records." from [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/basic-deliver.html), but no info on how to do this with CloudFormation

Answer (score 5):

Who ever is feeding your kinesis stream should add '\n' at the end.
See Java example below:

```
PutRecordRequest putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest(); 
putRecordRequest.setFirehoseName("incoming-stream"); 

String data = "some data" + "\n"; // add \n as a record separator 
Record record = new Record(); 
record.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))); 

putRecordRequest.setRecord(record); 
firehoseClient.putRecord(putRecordRequest);
```

See [source.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-kinesis-firehose-simple-highly-scalable-data-ingestion/)